# Is the following functional defined on the space of diffeomorphisms (or just vector space of $C^2$ functions) of Euclidean space convex?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, optimization, convex-optimization, calculus-of-variations

Let $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^d.$ Consider the functional $\Psi: Diffeo(\mathbb{R}^d) \to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ defined on the space $Diffeo(\mathbb{R}^d)$ of diffeomorphisms  of $\mathbb{R}^d$ defined by:

$$\Psi[F]:= ||F(x)-F(y)||_2^{2},$$

where $||.||_2$ denotes the Euclidean $2$-norm.

Then, is $\Psi$ convex at all points of $ Diffeo(\mathbb{R}^d) ?$ We note that if we let $F$ be $F(x):= \lambda x$ for a scalar $\lambda \ne 0,$ then writing $\Psi = \Psi_{\lambda},$ we get $\frac{\partial\Psi_{\lambda}}{\partial \lambda^2}= 2 ||x-y||^2 > 0,$ implying $\Psi$ is convex on the subset of $Diffeo(\mathbb{R}^d)$ defined by scaling. **But how do we calculate $\frac{\partial^{2}{\Psi}}{\partial F^2}$ to begin with? I need some help here!**

**To make the question a bit easy**, we can perhaps replace the diffeomophism group in the domain by an appropriate vector space ($Diffeo(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is an infinite dimensional manifold!) and can take $d=1$, *so now we consider instead:*

$$F:\mathcal{C}^2(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}, F[\psi]:=(\psi(x_1) - \psi(x_2)^2$$
How to calculate $\frac{\partial^{2}{\Psi}}{\partial {F^2}}$ as a bilinear form on $\mathcal{C}^2(\mathbb{R})$ and show that it's positive definite?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense to me. $F$ is not a function of $psi$

Comment: @DaniloGregorin Ah sorry, you're right! It's $\Psi$ that's a function of $F,$ I'll edit the question, thanks for pointing out! So I'm asking to compute $\frac{\partial^{2}{\Psi}}{\partial F^2}$ and show that it's positive definite.The problem I'm having is to calculate the Hessian here - the gradient calculation is easy.

Comment: How did you compute the first derivative? Taking the Gateaux derivative and showing that it is continuous? What was the result?

Comment: @DaniloGregorin I'll modify the question in couple of hours with the detail of my calculation. It's really taking the limit of the differences of linear pertubations that I considered, namely: $D\Psi_{F}[G]= lim_{t \to 0}(\Psi[F + tG] - \Psi[F])/t$. Note that $\Psi[F + tG]$ is still a diffeo for small $t.$ I think Gateaux derivative is the same as "total derivative"  (not the partials, but the total, as a linear map).

Comment: What you said is just the Gateaux, or directional, derivative (because you are approaching $F$ in the direction of $G$. If the Gateaux derivative exists and is continuous for all directions, then the functional is Fréchet differentiable(and this is the total derivative notion)

Comment: @DaniloGregorin I see, thanks for the precision on Gâteaux derivative. Yes it's the partial derivative, but I can't state the Fréchet (total) derivative in a basis-free manner, without telling what it's effect on each "direction" (here, $G$) is. But this part was easy, and i'm absolutely sure it's all continuous, but the question is: how do we define Hessian in a basis free manner here? I know it's the matrix of partial derivatives in finite dim, but we need a basis free definition here, and then verify that the symmetric $2$-form is indeed positive definite. Therein lies my problem.

Comment: I am not sure, have you tried computing the Gâteaux derivative of the derivative you have got?

Comment: @DaniloGregorin Sorry I didn't quite understand what you are not sure about - just so that I understand any point of disagreement.


On the other hand, how does computing Gâteaux derivative of the Gâteaux derivative help me exactly? (I'm guessing you didn't mean comuting Gçateaux derivative of the total/Fréchet derivative). What I need is the "second total/Fréchet derivative", i.e. Hessian $Hess[\Psi]$, and prove that it's positive definite, in order to prove that the functional $\Psi$ is convex.

Comment: I have not tried making the computations, but this is what I would try: you know that the Gateaux derivative exists and that it is continuous. Ok. Then this is the Fréchet derivative. Try computing the Gâteaux derivative of the map $\Psi': F \mapsto \psi'(F)$

Comment: In any case, you don't need the second derivative to show that a functional is convex. See Lemme 15.3 in the first chapter of Kavian's Introduction à la Théorie des Points Critiques

Comment: @DaniloGregorin Will do and update on the question, in couple of hours tops.

Comment: @DaniloGregorin I think you're right, enough to show that: for a small perturbation of the functional at it's critical point, the partial/Gâteaux derivatives all are +ve (Will be precise later). On the other hand, computing Hessian might be a learnign experience, as we're dealing with an ifinite dimensional differen tial manifolds here, which I'm sure carry some Rielannian structure. The Hessian can be defined at critical point w/o Riemannian structure, but if I recall correctly, it requires a Riemannian metric to be able to define Hessian at all other points. Anyway, i'll investigate.

Comment: I am sorry, I know nothing about riemannian geometry